# How to remove duplicate lines in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to remove duplicate lines in a div

```
<div id="content>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>why</p>
  <p>are</p>
  <p>hello</p>
</div>
```

The output is shown as

```
hello
why
are
hello
```

How can I remove the duplicate lines?

Comment: There are far too many solutions to this questions. show us what `jquery` code you have tried so we can narrow it down.

Comment: I found for the duplicates in array but not in div

Comment: you should explain us a bit more about your code. Where are these data coming from? How do you populate the div with data? If this is coming from some server side input (db) why don't you sanitize the input then? When this "removal" should happen? On user request?

Comment: if you have an array and you find duplicates there, just remove them from the array before using it!

Comment: @Daniel_ZA why Jquery? You can do it also with plain javascript or server side.

Comment: @LelioFaieta just thought I would point out Jquery since the title of the question was "javascript jquery"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are concerned about case, just remove the `.toLowerCase()`

```js
var seen = {};
$('#content>p').each(function() {
  var txt = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
  if (seen[txt])
    $(this).remove();
  else
    seen[txt] = true;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>why</p>
  <p>are</p>
  <p>hello</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use an object as map

```
var map = {};
$('p').each(function(){
    var value = $(this).text();
    if (map[value] == null){
        map[value] = true;
    } else {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate lines? Could you please post a screenshot of how it looks? Do you want the wording spaced closer to each other in the paragraph tags? If this is the case, try using CSS

```
#content {
    line-height: 0.5;
}
```

Also, you missed a " in id="content"